# Specify arbitrary attributes for code blocks and keep them when converting with pandoc

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, pandoc

Markdown and its different flavours have a number of interesting extensions, notably the [`hl_lines` attribute][0], which allows to highlight specific lines in a fenced code block, as illustrated [here](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/a11431539d08e14b0bd821ceb101fa59d6a74c8a/docs/extensions/fenced_code_blocks.md#syntax-highlighting) and [here](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/superfences/#highlighting-lines). This feature has actually been [implemented in ox-hugo](https://ox-hugo.scripter.co/doc/source-blocks/#highlighting) (export of org to Hugo-compatible markdown) by "hacking the `org-babel-exp-code`".

---

What I am trying to do is the following:

###### 1. specify arbitrary attributes in a code block

I can't find anything in the documentation for org-mode or emacs about adding arbitrary attributes to a code block through some kind of header. The kind of syntax I would have expected:

```
#+begin_src python attr:"hl_lines='2'"
```

```
#+begin_src python :hl_line "2"
```

```
#+attr_markdown: :hl_lines 2
#+begin_src: python
```

###### 2. export an org file to Markdown (either through `org-md-export-to-markdown` or `org-pandoc-export-to-markdown`/`commonmark`/etc.) in a way that keeps the attributes

`pandoc` [does not support](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1183) `hl_lines`, and cuts off anything that comes after `python` in `#+begin_src python ....` when exporting (tried both from emacs and from the pandoc CLI).

To be clear, I am trying to find a solution in `pandoc` to avoid having to deal with the many idiosyncrasies of `org-md-export-to-markdown` I have to face with my specific files.

###### 3. deploy the Markdown files through a service that can understand the `hl_line` attribute

This last step is solved.

---

Is implementing this feature in `pandoc` the only way or is there some workaround I haven't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by writing a pandoc filter that inserts any custom parameters into the markdown output. The code and the shell command are available here: [Keep custom code block attributes in pandoc when converting to Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70733164/keep-custom-code-block-attributes-in-pandoc-when-converting-to-markdown).

In theory, I can run `org-pandoc-export-to-commonmark` and specify my filter as a command option in the org file with the line below:

```
#+PANDOC_OPTIONS: filter:/full/path/to/pandoc/filters/keep_attributes_markdown.py
```

However, even though the command runs correctly and the filter is supposedly used, the output still corresponds to what it would be without the filter, but this is a separate bug that I will raise in https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc.